# HTTPServletResponse status code is not in HTTP response header

Tags: java, web-services, rest, servlets, http-headers

I have pretty simple JAX-RS WS:

```
@Stateless
@Path("/foo")
public class FooFacadeBean {     

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String performFooCall(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.setStatus(500);
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

After deployment I execute: curl -v localhost:8080/foo, 
the result was:

```
About to connect() to localhost port 8080
Trying 127.0.0.1...
connected
Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080
GET /foo HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.26.0
Host: localhost:8080
Accept: */

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2 Java/Sun Microsystems Inc./1.6)
Server: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 26 Jul 2012 13:52:10 GMT

Hello 

Connection to host localhost left intact
Closing connection
```

As you can see status code in HTTP hasn't changed at all, despite of it was set manually.
Why does this happen? I've spent a lot of hours googling without any results.

Such workaround as returning Response object, something like this:

```
Response.status(404).entity("Hello").build();
```

works perfectly!

Glassfish uses JERSEY as JAX-RS implementation. I use embedded variant of Glassfish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, that's not how you should use Jersey.

Here's what's happening:

- The method executes, and you interact with the ServletResponse and set the status code to 500. But since you don't write any data, the response isn't committed.
- Then the method returns a String value. Since Jersey has no way of knowing if you've interacted with the ServletResponse or not, it behaves normally.
- A String method that returns implies a 200 response code (void implies 204, etc). Jersey tries to set the response code to the default, ultimately by calling `setStatus(200)` on the response instance. Since the response hasn't been committed yet, this isn't a problem, and the response of 500 is changed to 200.
- The HttpServletResponse is committed and is sent back to the client.

I'm assuming that what you want to do is return a different status code, but in an exceptional case only. The way to do that is to return a String in the normal case, and then throw a [WebApplicationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException.html) in the exceptional case.

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String performFooCall() {
    if (isNormal()) {
        return "Hello";
    }
    throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(500).entity("Hello").build());
}
```

Alternatively, you can throw a standard exception, and control how it is rendered as a response with a separate [ExceptionMapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html).

Comment: You are right, I am not so much familiar with this workflow. Could you give me a reference? Also what should I do to commit the HttpServletResponse?

Comment: @Steve: basically, don't deal with HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse at all if you're using Jax-RS. For more info, see the Jersey User Guide here: http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/index.html

Comment: thanks for the help, I'll read the manual thoroughly. By the way, I forgot to say that when I wrote client for this case with JERSEY API and got Response status code it was 500. As I understand after your explanation - this is internal framework workflow.

Answer (score -1):

Jersey building a new response so setting the response code in your code, is override later.
You have to build a new response in your code and put you string in the response (and change your return value for that), or you can create a filter that will work later on in the filter chaing and change the response status.

look [here](http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Setting-Response-Status-td4745399.html) for more details