# Httpresponse with no body?

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, http-status

I am setting `HttpServletResponse` status code and `content` like this:

```
    httpResponse.setStatus(getHttpStatusCode());

    if (responseContentNotEmpty()){
       PrintWriter writer;
        try {

            writer = httpResponse.getWriter();
            writer.write(jsonContent);
            writer.close();


            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

`getHttpStatusCode()` returns a valid status code.

I set content only on certain requests. For example if a `DELETE` request I have no content to set, then the `responseContentNotEmpty()`
 returns false and content block is not executed.

However, when no content is set I get a 204 (NO CONTENT) status code even though I set a status code of 200 (OK) using `httpResponse.setStatus()`.

How can I get the status code I set even though I don't set content ??

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: @Lee: I am using REST with Java (JAX-RS) using Jersey

Comment: That is because you are setting the status but not committing it, your function might be returning void which is setting the status code to 204 and committing the response. Exactly what framework are you using? Jersey API would solve it I guess. Came across this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671190/httpservletresponse-status-code-is-not-in-http-response-header

Comment: @Pratyay: I printed the function `getHttpStatusCode()` returned value and it's a valid status code

Comment: @Pratyay: Yes you are right I return void, thus 204 get returned. So there is no way to return my status code (like 404) without setting content in `httpServletResponse` ?? As when I set content it works but not without it